# How to start a state machine workflow at a certain state activity (restart after failure)?

Tags: workflow, error-handling, state-machine

Is there a way to start a SP2010 state machine workflow at a specific state activity?

For example, if I have state A -> B -> C -> D is is possible to start at C?

The idea is I have an workflow that does some stuff and at some point can fail, mainly because of configuration problems or data missing. After I fix the configuration or add the missing data I want to continue from the state it failed at.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to store the current state (e.g. during State initialization )in a workflow variable and then use the Set State activity as soon as you start and check that value, and act upon it.

Have a look here for more details http://wiki.windowsworkflowfoundation.eu/default.aspx/WF/SetStateActivity.html

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Just some additions to your answer, if I may! Once a workflow fails you can't restart it! You have to cancel it and start a brand new one. Saving something in the Workflow is thus useless so you have to determine the state to jump to based on external factors (which luckily I could). You do that in the worflow activated event (when the new workflow starts) then jump to the desired state with Set State activity.

Comment: You are right about your notes, however, by incorporating strong error handling techniques, instead of failing, you could revert to some default/initial state, which in a State machine workflow could also mean moving to another state, instead of END-ing the WF, as in the case of Sequential WF.