# How to continue workflow from error step?

Tags: 2010, workflow, error

I have a workflow with error occured status. I fixed the error and  deployed the .wsp file. Now I need to continue this workflow from a code activity where error occured. Are there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Related question that may help you: [How to start a state machine workflow at a certain state activity (restart after failure)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34691/how-to-start-a-state-machine-workflow-at-a-certain-state-activity-restart-after)

Is your workflow sequence or state machine? From what I gather, unless your workflow was designed to be fault tolerant to begin with (perhaps with an "error" state) you'll probably just have to restart all running instances such that your updated workflow can go into effect. Also, remember to bounce the SharePoint timer job service to avoid cache retention of your old DLLs.